# How to write 4 bytes continuous data without any SCK delay through SPI with Pic18f45k20

Tags: microcontroller, pic, spi, microchip

In pic18f45k20, I have to write 4byte data at once without any setup SCK delay through SPI. Is there any way to cancel the SCK delay while sending 4 bytes together?(like Assembly)I am using MPLAB-XC8 and hitech c. In 10Mhz SPI, I got 460ns SCK delay between two bytes. However, I would like to cancel that delay to write 4byte data at once.

Comment: If you manually bitbang two pins you can shave off some time, if you use the hardware peripheral I think some dead time between transfers is inevitable.

Answer (score 4):

Cite from the 18F4550 datasheet, which should be the same concerning SPI:

> In  receive  operations,  SSPSR and SSPBUF  together create a  double-buffered receiver.  When  SSPSR receives  a  complete byte, it  is  transferred  to SSPBUF and the SSPIF interrupt  is  set.
>
> During  transmission, the SSPBUF is  not doublebuffered.  A  write to SSPBUF will  write to both SSPBUF and SSPSR.

`SSPBUF` is a 1-byte buffer and `SSPSR` is a shift register actually connected to the IO pins.

This means the master effectively does not have a buffer for sending data.  After sending a byte, a new byte has to be written to the `SSPBUF`, and a new transmission process has to be triggered. This always takes time noticeable as delay between byte transmissions.

If reducing SPI speed until the delay is neglible is not OK, you have to implement the SPI transfer in software. This will be slower than the faster SPI hardware modes!

Keep in mind the different clock cycles the instructions need. You will need several `NOP`s to get a well defined SPI signal with a 50% clock duty cycle.  I did this some years ago and can show it end of this week, as I'm currently on vacation.

The microchip libraries offer software SPI, too. But I doubt they can do multi byte transmissions seamlessly.